# Execute() method of ForkJoinPool class

Tags: java, fork-join, forkjoinpool

Here is what the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#invoke%28java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask%29) says about it:

> ```
> public void execute(Runnable task)
>
> Description copied from interface: Executor
> Executes the given command at some time in the future. The command may execute in a new thread, in a pooled thread, or in the calling
> ```
>
> thread, at the discretion of the Executor implementation.
>
> ```
> Parameters:
>     task - the runnable task
> Throws:
>     NullPointerException - if the task is null
>     RejectedExecutionException - if the task cannot be scheduled for execution
> ```

ForkJoinPool is already an implementation of ExecutorService? what are they talking about? How do I know the behaviour of such a method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you are asking here, but yes `ForkJoinPool` is an implementation of `ExecutorService`. The `execute(Runnable)` method will schedule a task to be executed by the `ForkJoinPool`. This task will get executed when a worker thread in the pool is free to conduct such a task. It is essentially the same as `submit(Runnable)` except that it does not return a `ForkJoinTask` (In fact if you check the source code you will see that both methods do the same thing, except `execute` doesn't return the task it submits).

Comment: In the API of the ForkJoinPool it says that it is implementation dependent. However ForkJoinPool is already an implementation so I think they mistook stating in the ForkJoinPool API that execute(Runnable run) depends how it is implemented... they should have specified the behaviour implemented in the ForkJoinPool

Comment: Ah yes, it does look like they got a bit lazy with the javadoc on this one.